# EM 13c - Custom Views for Incident Manager

Tags: oracle, dataguard

## EM 13c Cloud control

Looking to create Custom view for DataGuard incidents in the Incident Manager of the Cloud Control.

Following is the Current search criteria I used for my custom view:

```
Shows open
Incidents and Problems
Updated in the last 31 days
Target types: Database Instance
Target and all members
Category: Availability
Summary Contains ORA-16810
```

Question: Want to specify more than one ORA- in the Summary field. Is it possible to place multiple values using OR condition?

I already tried |, double quotes, single quotes for each value and found no success.
Search in the Metalink did not lead to any examples for the Summary field.

ORA-16810 OR ORA-16853

Comment: The following string in the Summary field did *not* work. FYI.
.*ORA-(16810|16853).*